# TFS permissions to create Team Projects in a specific collection

Tags: reporting-services, tfs, permissions, team-project

We have several Collections in our TFS 2010 server.
This server hosts all of our TFS related services.

I'd like to allow a specific programmer to create Team Projects within his dedicated collection.
He belongs to the collection's TFS administrators group.
When he tries to create a new Team Project, it fails with a Reporting permissions error.
I understand that he also needs Reporting services permissions to create the relevant Reporting objects for the new Team Project, but I don't want him to be a full admin for the whole server's Reporting Services.

Is there a way to allow him the full ability to create new Team Projects without making a full Reporting Services admin?

Comment: I have encoutered this problem myself also, but it seems to be an omission in the TFS collection awareness at the report server. Generating a new TFS project in the report server requires root access because the Report server actually does not know of the concept of TFS collections ...

Comment: Can you include the actual Reporting Services error from the Project Creation Wizard log? TFS also adds a new role to SSRS called 'Team Foundation Content Manager', this should be enough to create new folders under /TfsReports/

Comment: The error the user is getting is:
TF218027: The following reporting could not be created on the server that is running SQL Server Reporting Services:
/TfsReports/DefaultCollection

Comment: continue error message:
...The report server is located at: http://tfssrv/Reports. The error is: The permissions granted to the user '****\****' are insufficient for performing this operation. Verify that the path is correct and that you have sufficient permissions to create a folder on that server, and then try again.
------------------
error end

The user was trying to create a Team Project called "common".
The user has collection administrator permissions.

Answer (score 8):

source:http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8175
To grant administrative permissions for a team project collection in Reporting Services

1. Start Internet Explorer.
2. In the Address bar, type the following URL, where ReportServer is the name of the server that is running Reporting Services: http://ReportServer/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx
3. Click the Properties tab, and then click New Role Assignment.
4. In Group or User Name, type the name of the account for the user or group to whom you want grant administrative permissions.
5. In Role, click Team Foundation Content Manager, and then click OK.

The one thing missing in the manual, is that you need to do this for /TfsReports/[collectionname] while setting stop security inheratence.