# TF218027 Error When User Creates New Team Project

Tags: tfs

I have a user who gets the following error when they attempt to create a New Team Project:

> TF218027: The following reporting folder could not be created on the
>   server that is running SQL Server Reporting Services[...]

After several attempts to fix using feedback from this site as well as others, I have narrowed down the problem somewhat, but not sure what to do next.

The user is in the appropriate group in SSRS, with Content Manager and Team Foundation Content Manager roles. I have also broken the permission inheretance per [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214632/tfs-permissions-to-create-team-projects-in-a-specific-collection) stackoverflow article.

The odd thing I have observed is that by putting the user into SSRS directly, it works. By being a member of a group instead, it does not work.

Any advise would be appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 1):

Windows group memberships are only refreshed on log on. If you added the user to the group right now, the user might need to log off and log on again to get the new group membership into effect.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The user exited out of Visual Studio each time he tested it.  Since I made the post, he has rebooted and I even bounced the TFS server.  Still not working.